# SVN serve refuse. telnel ::1 3690 success, but fail telnet 127.0.0.1

Tags: svn

Cannot connect to svn//localhost with Windows 7

"telnet localhost 3690"  and "telnet ::1  3690"  both success
but "telnet 127.0.0.1 3690" failed  at port 3690

That drives me crazy.

netstat shows:

```
TCP   [::]:3690     [::]:0      LISTENNING    5308
```

Comment: I don't know why anyone is trying to close this a "of-topic" as it **is** a question about a programming tool.

Answer (score 2):

Your svn client seems not to support or prefer IPv6, and your server seems to be bound to IPv6 only. Either enable the client to use IPv6 (by replacing http://localhost/ with http://[::1]/) or force the svn server to use IPv4 by specifying the command line option `--listen-host 0.0.0.0`.